# Laravel 5.0 destroy method

Tags: laravel-5

I can figure out why i am not accessing me destroy method.
Blade:

```
@foreach($advertisements as $advertisement)
<form class="form-horizontal" method="delete" action="advertisements/{{ $advertisement->id }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <h2> {{ $advertisement->title }}</h2>
                    {{$advertisement->city}} {{ $advertisement->type }}
                        <input class="btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete add">
                </div>
        </form>
```

Controller:

```
public function destroy($advertisements)
{
    Advertisement::find($advertisements)->delete();

    return redirect('advertisements');

}
```

route:list
| DELETE | advertisements/{advertisements} | advertisements.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\AdvertisementsController@destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing),

> HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request method:

You should update your form tag and add a hidden input field _method:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="advertisements/{{ $advertisement->id }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

Comment: Ohh i should knew that. Thanks a lot!